# Exclude text from HEREDOC

Tags: php

I need to place long, multiline text into variable.
But with 'comments', small portion of the text the shouldn't be in the result.

Pseudocode:

```
$var = <<<MULTILINETEXT
  Some text {//Excluded from output}
  Some text2 {//Excluded from output}
MULTILINETEXT;
```

$var after this:

```
Some text
Some text2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not use HEREDOC or not use COMMENTS

Comment: You can't use comments in a HEREDOC.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: He can use comments in heredoc but interpreter will treat it as a string not as a comment. it will look like this after execution Some text {//Excluded from output} Some text2 {//Excluded from output}

Comment: If your HEREDOC text is long and complex enough to warrant comments, you might consider the MVC pattern! A pure PHP template (view), or twig, or blade etc., could all support inline comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here use a reg expression to ignore the string that enclosed in between the { and }.

```
$var = <<<MULTILINETEXT
  Some text {//Excluded from output}
  Some text2 {//Excluded from output}
MULTILINETEXT;
$var = preg_replace("/\{[^}]+\}/", "", $var);
print_r($var);
```

Comment: It works! Great idea! Please make you Answer more readable and i will accept

Comment: it's my pleasure !!